# Is using if-let discouraged in emacs-lisp?

Tags: elisp-macros

I wrote a piece of code using `if-let`. Later, when I tried to use my function, I got:

```
Symbol’s function definition is void: if-let
```

So I found that `if-let` is defined in `subr-x.el` and I need to use `(require 'subr-x)` in my code.

My question is: Is using `if-let` discouraged in emacs-lisp?

Comment: it is defined in `subr.el`; v29.1

Comment: "Discouraged" how? By whom? Why do you ask? The question seems to encourage opinion-based answers.

Comment: Oh, no. Sorry! It was not my intention. It's just that I recently discovered `if-let` and it seemed strange, to me, that in my Emacs (26.3) it is necessary to use `(require 'subr-x)`. I had doubts that using `if-let` wasn't good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not discouraged for users. However, `if-let` is in `subr-x` because that's not pre-loaded into Emacs before dumping, unlike `subr`, and the Emacs devs want to limit unneeded bloat in the base image. `if-let` is after all some pretty trivial syntactic sugar over `if` and `let`.